# PHP - How to validate textfield input (Zip-Code, Phonenumber) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

first of all, I just started to get into PHP, so I have literally no clue what I am doing

I am currently building a new E-Commerce website with WordPress & WooCommerce.

I am looking for a way to validate custom field input for the phone & zipcode field.

Here is a testing link for the form: https://www.goodfeelingpower.com/test/

Both fields are "billing" information for the WooCommerce Checkout. Therefore I need to make sure that I can set some rules for the input.

I tried to work around with this code here for the ZIP-Code:

```
// Rules for postcode input
function postcode_validate() {
    $billing_postcode = input($post["postcode"]); {
        if (is_page('test')
            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{0,5}$/",$billing_postcode))
                $billing_postcodeErr = "Invalid Postcode";
    }
}
```

However, I can still input a postcode like "ABC7560123". I want to regulate the input field on 5 numbers. The same thing I am planning to do with the phone field, but I can't get my code currently working for the postcode field.

I as well would like to give a short message out like "please enter a valid zipcode". I would like to insert the PHP code into my function.php file of my child theme.

I am so thankful for any help guys :)

Best regards,

Marius

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should work nicely:

```
/^\d{5}$/
$number = '12345';
if(!preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $number))
echo "please enter a valid zipcode\n";
```

This will check if a string consists of only 5 numbers.

/ is the delimiter. It is at the beginning and the end of a regular expression. (User-defined, you can use any character as delimiter).

^ is a start of string anchor.

\d is a shorthand for [0-9], which is a character class matching only digits.

{5} means repeat the last group or character 5 times.

$ is the end of string anchor.

/ is the closing delimiter.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot Nagender, how can I implement this code, that it only applies for my ZipCode field?

Comment: Actually i am not aware from what you wrote code for validation but according to your above code, you can put this code snippet where you want to validate. Like below-
<code>
// Rules for postcode input
function postcode_validate() {
    $billing_postcode = input($post["postcode"]); {
        if (is_page('test')
           // validation rule
           if(!preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $billing_postcode))
                $billing_postcodeErr = "please enter a valid zipcode";
    }
}
</code>